# Updating component variable when variable declared in service is updated

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to update a variable declared in my component when the variable declared in my service changes. I am using Subject for this. However, nothing happens.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ShareDataService } from './share-data.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ShareDataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareDataService } from './share-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  _subscription;
  constructor(private shareDataService:ShareDataService)
  {
    //this.title=this.shareDataService.title;
    this._subscription = shareDataService.titleChange.subscribe((value) => { 
      this.title = value; 
      //alert(this.title);
      console.log("COmponent::::::::::::::"+this.title);
    });
  }
}
```

**shareDataService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class ShareDataService {
  title:string="TITLE";
  titleChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(
      function()
      {

      this.title="BACDEF";

      //console.log(this.title);
      this.titleChange.next(this.title);
    }
    ,1000);
   }
}
```

It gives an error saying "Cannot read property 'next' of undefined" for the Subject defined in service. What would be the most appropriate way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.title="BACDEF";
  this.titleChange.next(title);
}, 1000)
```

or bind:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.title="BACDEF";
  this.titleChange.next(title);
}.bind(this), 1000)
```

to get rid of that error. Otherwise `this` in setTimeout's callback is a window object

Comment: what's the best way to inform component about changes in multiple variables of a service? Is using Subject the best way?

Comment: Subject is a natural (I would say) way to inform components about changes. And as @cyberpirate92 wrote, most likely you need a BehaviorSubject. Because when you inject a service, component's constructor needs an instance of that service. And because services doesnt have life cycle hooks - only the constructor method, your component gets that instance when service's Subject already received next(). In other words - constructor subscribes after service calls next() on Subject. But if you use BehaviorSubject, it remembers the last value.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the most appropriate way to implement this?

You can use a [`BehaviorSubject`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#BehaviorSubject) instead of a `Subject`, because

- Upon subscription BehaviorSubject returns the last value whereas the `Subject` doesn't trigger until `onnext`, So using a `BehaviorSubject` you don't have to be worried about your components having the latest data, no matter when you subscribe.
- If you want to retrieve the last value of the `BehaviorSubject` in a non-observable code (without a subscription), you can always use the `getValue()` method.

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/behaviorsubject-example)